# Many to many reverse relationship Django

Tags: python, sql, django, database-administration

I am trying to write a simple messages system.

Basically I have a User table and a Message table.

```
class User(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User)# inherit djangos default user properties
   messages = models.ManyToManyField(Message)
```

.

```
class Message(models.Model):
   date = models.DateField()
   text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

I want to be able to add as many users to as many messages as possible.

I want to be able to say messages.users and users.messages.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel - use [django-messages](https://github.com/arneb/django-messages/tree/master/django_messages). Or, at least, take a look on it's [models](https://github.com/arneb/django-messages/blob/master/django_messages/models.py).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't define the relationship on both sides. Pick one - probably Messages - and define it there. Django automatically provides the reverse relationship.

Also, you don't need a separate User class, especially if the M2M field is on messages itself. So, you can just do this:

```
class Message(models.Model):
   date = models.DateField()
   text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   users = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User')
```

And now you can access the messages for a user with `my_user.message_set.all()`, and the users for a message with `my_messages.users.all()`.